# Can I use the Office 2007 Proofing Tools with Office 2010 RTM?

Tags: compatibility, language, microsoft-office-2010, proofing

I have just downloaded and installed Office 2010 RTM. Overall, it is very nice, but I miss having proofing tools available for my native language, Danish.
I have installed the 2007 Proofing Tools, but they do not work with 2010:

> For this release we have made significant changes in the proofing infrastructure, therefore  the Language Packs from previous Office versions including Office 2007 are not compatible with Office 2010.

(http://blogs.msdn.com/naturallanguage/archive/2009/07/16/proofing-tools-in-office-2010.aspx)

Does anyone know a workaround until the 2010 Proofing Tools are released?

Thank you,
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localizations and proofing tools are usually released month-or-two after RTM.

This timeline is based on how everything worked with Office 2007 and it's language packs (and proofing tools).